# How do I position h:message to the right of a h:inputText?

Tags: jsf, facelets

My xhtml page code:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Email address: " />
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{userBean.emailAddressBeingEdited}" required="true" requiredMessage="*" />
<h:message for="email" id="emailM"/>
```

My java code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("email", new FacesMessage("Email already in use"));
```

I tried nesting the h:message in the h:inputText, but that did not work. If I need to provide more information, please ask.

Comment: @EJP: they do match. The `emailM` is the `id` of the `<h:message>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client ID which you specify in `addMessage()` has to be the real client ID, not the component ID. The client ID of an input component is usually prefixed with the ID of the parent form component. For starters who haven't memorized which JSF components implement [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) and how client IDs are generated, the easiest way to find out the real client ID is to open the page in browser, view its source and locate the generated HTML `<input type="text">` element and finally take its `id`. If you have given the `<h:form>` an ID of `formId`, it'll be `formId:email`. That's the real client ID which you need to specify in `addMessage()`.

```
context.addMessage("formId:email", message);
```

If you don't specify the right client ID, then the message remains unhandled. If the JSF project stage is set to `Development`, then JSF will automatically append it in a list of "unhandled messages" in the end of the body. This is what you're seeing. View the generated HTML source to see it yourself, it's the autogenerated HTML list `<ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages">`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you seem to be doing the validation in the JSF bean action method. This is not the right way. You should be using a `Validator` for this. This way you don't need to worry about the client IDs. You just need to throw a `ValidatorException` with a `FacesMessage`. E.g.

```
@FacesValidator("uniqueEmailValidator")
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        // ...

        if (emailIsAlreadyInUse) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Email is already in use", null));
        }
    }

}
```

which you then register as `<f:validator validatorId="uniqueEmailValidator" />` inside the input component.

Comment: Does he really have to add all the parent ids? I have plenty of JSF code that doesn't.

Comment: @EJP: Apparently you're using `<h:form prependId="false">` or you're using a somewhat different JSF implementation/library.

Comment: I'm using Mojarra. Never set prepend="false" in my life :-) and the ids are certainly compound.

Comment: @EJP: I can assure what BalusC state above are correct, as they are stated in the JSF spec as well. In JSF, component client id are constructed by concatenate component that implement NamingContainer with the targeted component id, unless `prependId="false"` is set

Comment: I suspect the truth is that I'm not using literals for id's at all, I am getting them from the component being validated.

Answer (score 3):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
   <h:outputLabel value="Email address: " />
   <h:inputText id="email" value="#{userBean.emailAddressBeingEdited}" required="true" requiredMessage="*" />
   <h:message for="email" id="emailM"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

this??

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that unfortunately just puts the error message underneath everything else and not to the right of the h:inputText box.

Comment: Update: This answer was good, I was just using the wrong id. I'd vote it up, but I don't have enough reputation yet.